# Insert token into header as http call

Tags: angular, token

I am having the code:

```
const parameters = 'Account/GetDoctorDetails?userId=' + 63;
this.http.get(`${webserviceUrlLocalHost}` + parameters)
.subscribe(response => {
  console.log('response.json()');
  console.log(response.json());
```

I would like to insert into this call a token into the GET webapi call, so i changed my code to:

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': `Bearer ` + token });
const options2 = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get('http://localhost:55803/Account/GetDoctorDetails?userId=63', options2)
    .subscribe( response => console.log(response.json())); */
```

But the function is never call; any idea why it doesn' t work ?

Answer (score 0):

try `new HttpHeaders` instead of `new RequestOptions` ( [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions) ),
from the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) :

add the headers like :

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

so your `options2` should be :

```
const options2 = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ` + token
  })
};
```

Comment: Hi Taki, i got the error when change to your code: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
      Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.

Answer (score 0):

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .append('Authorization',`Bearer ` + token );
let params = new HttpParams()
                .append('userId', '63')

return new Observable<any>(observer => {
                this.http.get('your-Rest-API-URL', { headers ,params}).subscribe((response) => {
                    observer.next(response);
                    observer.complete();
                }, (error) => { });
            });
```

Comment: Hi, I don' t see why there are so many ways to do the same thing ?

Comment: Not a different way, just tried to ease up the code by removing the hardcoded part such as userId in your case.